# How to preserve whitespace but ignore line breaks in CSS?

Tags: html, css

The `white-space` property in CSS-3 has the `pre-wrap` value, which will preserve whitespace and line breaks, and wrap when necessary, and the `pre-line` value, which collapses whitespace, but preserves line breaks, and wraps when necessary.

What it does *not* have, though, is a value that **preserves** whitespace and **collapses** line breaks, while still wrapping otherwise.

Is there a combination of other CSS properties that I can use to get this effect?

For example:

```
This  example
code
should     render
on  one  line  but
with spaces     intact.
```

should look like:

```
This  example code should     render on  one  line  but with spaces     intact.
```

Comment: There is no pure CSS. `white-space` is oddly lacking in this respect. Can you use JavaScript?

Comment: This seems unlikely to ever be a part of the spec.  I can't think of a single use case where this would be helpful, but you should still be able to pull this off with some very minimal javascript.

Comment: If such a property would exist, one problem would be CRLF combinations. If you don't want white spaces to collapse, should both the CR and the LF count as one space?

Comment: The only way I can see to do this is with JavaScript: https://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/co9wqjmp/2

Comment: @MrLister If I were in charge of adding it to the spec, I would use the segment break rules already in place - https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#segment-normalization - which treat CR, LF, and CRLF each as a single segment break.

Comment: @JosephMarikle You meant to replace the newlines with spaces. https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/co9wqjmp/4/

Comment: @MrLister Oops.  Yeah.  That makes more sense.

Comment: You could also replace spaces with non-breaking spaces, without needing any CSS:  https://jsfiddle.net/xc5nmpuj/

Comment: @JosephMarikle I had a sinking feeling it was going to be something like that.

Comment: Or, you could hard code the spaces as non-breaking spaces and then you won't even need JavaScript. https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/xc5nmpuj/2/

Comment: @MrLister The data is coming in from a database, so I don't have control over that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Answer to your question**: no, there is no way to do it by only using `CSS` ([prove](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/whitespace/) for `white-space`)

[image: behaviors of all the different values for white-space prop]
There is no line such as: *collapse* | *preserve* | ...

The only way to do it is by using `JavaScript`

```js
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/\n/g, '');
```

```css
html {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
This  example
code
should     render
on  one  line  but
with spaces     intact.
```

**Hardcode methods**

---

1st

```css
* {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

br {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
This  example<br/>code<br/>should     render<br/>on  one  line  but<br/>with spaces     intact.<br/>
```

---

2nd

```html
This&nbsp; example
code
should &nbsp; &nbsp; render
on&nbsp; one&nbsp; line&nbsp; but
with spaces &nbsp; &nbsp; intact.
```