# js: using += with a list (blackjack)

Tags: javascript, arrays

im coding a blackjack game on js. right at the top of the code is a `card` array with existing cards in the hand

```
let firstCard = 10
let secondCard = 4
let cards = [firstCard, secondCard]
```

there is a button labelled "new card" (with a value of 6 in this case) which adds a new card to the `card` array:

```
   function newCard() {
    let card = 6
    cards.push(card)
    console.log(cards)
    renderGame()
}
```

in the renderGame() function, an html element `cardsEL` shows the card numbers in the hand:

```
function renderGame() {
    cardsEl.textContent = "Cards: "
    for (i = 0; i < cards.length; i++){
        cardsEl.textContent += cards[i] += " "
    }
```

why does the console.log print out `["10 ", "4 ", 6]` with 10 and 4 having a space after them while 6 doesn't? according to `cardsEl.textContent += cards[i] += " "`, all elements in `cards` should have a spacing after them?

another question: for this line `cardsEl.textContent += cards[i] += " "`, does js solve `cards[i] += " "` for each element in the `cards` list first before adding each "solved" element to `cardsEl.textContent`?

Comment: "*does js solve `cards[i] += " "` for each element in the cards list*" - yes. And don't do that. You don't want to assign strings as elements of `cards`. You want to use `cardsEl.textContent += cards[i] + " ";`.

Comment: There *is* a space after the `6` in the HTML. You just don't see it, as whitespace is collapsed when rendering. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/36727490/1048572

Answer (score 1):

```
cardsEl.textContent += cards[i] += " "
```

Change the += following `cards[i]` to just a +. Otherwise you're adding a space to `cards[i]` itself rather than to `cardsEl.textContent`.

```
cardsEl.textContent += cards[i] + " "
```